# Fetch data from monthly table MySQL based on date range (ex-data between 01-Jan-2016 to 01-April-2016)

Tags: php, mysql

I have monthly database tables which store daily user  signup count  of my website.in my UI design I have daterange piker between two date I have to get sum of signup user between date range provided .(But there will be 4 OR 5 many month between date range (based on date range)) How I will get data ? I need optimised solution so I will get that sum of data from multiple mysql tables.

```
CREATE TABLE daily_analytics_01_2017 ( 
id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
country varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
device varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
browser varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
gender varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, u
ser_loginCount int(11) NOT NULL, 
user_signup_count int(11) NOT NULL, 
tracking_date date NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (id) ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Above table for each month name like

daily_analytics_MONTH_YEAR

along with this all data for login and other action on my site I have to track on monthly basis .

Comment: can you share table structure?

Comment: Why do you have an extra table for this when you can simply add a signup date to the user table? Doing this you simply need to pull the data where that date is within your range (month)

Comment: CREATE TABLE `daily_analytics_01_2017` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `country` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `device` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `browser` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_loginCount` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_signup_count` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tracking_date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


Above table for each month name like daily_analytics_<MONTH>_<YEAR>

Comment: From that code it looks like you are creating a table for each month of data. Thats going to increase the table count.

Comment: Yes But I have to maintain other analytics also for signup,login,set password etc other user management task.On Daily Basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Following Function to built query:

```
function getMonthWiseQuery($fromdate,$todate)
{

    $fromexplode=explode("-",$fromdate);
    $startyear=$fromexplode[0];
    $startmonth=$fromexplode[1];
    $startdate=$fromexplode[2];


    $toexplode=explode("-",$todate);
    $endyear=$toexplode[0];
    $endmonth=$toexplode[1];
    $enddate=$toexplode[2];

    $queryBuild=array();
    $startmonthnew = $startmonth;
    $count=0;
    for ($i = $startyear; $i <= $endyear; $i++) {
        for ($j = $startmonthnew; $j < 13; $j++) {

                $count++;
                if ($fromdate) {

                    if (strlen($j) == 1) {
                        $j = "0" . $j;
                    }
                    if($count!=1)
                    {
                        $query=" UNION ALL";
                        $query.= " select sum(user_with_referral) as Total_UserBy_referral,sum(total_unverified_users) as TotalUnverifiedUsers,sum(user_signup_count) as TotalRegisteredUsers,sum(user_signUpactivationSuccess_count) as TotalActivatedUsers from daily_analytics_{$j}_{$i} where tracking_date BETWEEN \"{$fromdate}\" and \"{$todate}\" ";
                    }else{
                        $query = "select sum(user_with_referral) as Total_UserBy_referral,sum(total_unverified_users) as TotalUnverifiedUsers,sum(user_signup_count) as TotalRegisteredUsers,sum(user_signUpactivationSuccess_count) as TotalActivatedUsers from daily_analytics_{$j}_{$i} where tracking_date BETWEEN \"{$fromdate}\" and \"{$todate}\" ";
                    }

                    array_push($queryBuild,$query);

                }

            if ($j == 12) {
                $startmonthnew = 1;
                break;
            }

            if ($endyear == $i) {
                if ($j == $endmonth) {
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
    }

return implode(" ",$queryBuild);
}
```

Function will return union query with all table in date range-

```
    select sum(user_with_referral) as Total_UserBy_referral,sum(total_unverified_users) as TotalUnverifiedUsers,sum(user_signup_count) as TotalRegisteredUsers,sum(user_signUpactivationSuccess_count) as TotalActivatedUsers from daily_analytics_01_2017 where tracking_date BETWEEN "2017-01-01" and "2017-03-21"  
UNION ALL 
select sum(user_with_referral) as Total_UserBy_referral,sum(total_unverified_users) as TotalUnverifiedUsers,sum(user_signup_count) as TotalRegisteredUsers,sum(user_signUpactivationSuccess_count) as TotalActivatedUsers from daily_analytics_02_2017 where tracking_date BETWEEN "2017-01-01" and "2017-03-21"  
UNION ALL 
select sum(user_with_referral) as Total_UserBy_referral,sum(total_unverified_users) as TotalUnverifiedUsers,sum(user_signup_count) as TotalRegisteredUsers,sum(user_signUpactivationSuccess_count) as TotalActivatedUsers from daily_analytics_03_2017 where tracking_date BETWEEN "2017-01-01" and "2017-03-21"
```

Then from this query we can fetch sum of total result from UNion of tables-

```
   select sum(Total_UserBy_referral) as Total_UserBy_referral , sum(TotalUnverifiedUsers) as TotalUnverifiedUsers,sum(TotalRegisteredUsers) as TotalRegisteredUsers, sum(TotalActivatedUsers) as TotalActivatedUsers from (
select sum(user_with_referral) as Total_UserBy_referral,sum(total_unverified_users) as TotalUnverifiedUsers,sum(user_signup_count) as TotalRegisteredUsers,sum(user_signUpactivationSuccess_count) as TotalActivatedUsers from daily_analytics_01_2017 where tracking_date BETWEEN "2017-01-01" and "2017-03-21"  
UNION ALL 
select sum(user_with_referral) as Total_UserBy_referral,sum(total_unverified_users) as TotalUnverifiedUsers,sum(user_signup_count) as TotalRegisteredUsers,sum(user_signUpactivationSuccess_count) as TotalActivatedUsers from daily_analytics_02_2017 where tracking_date BETWEEN "2017-01-01" and "2017-03-21"  
UNION ALL 
select sum(user_with_referral) as Total_UserBy_referral,sum(total_unverified_users) as TotalUnverifiedUsers,sum(user_signup_count) as TotalRegisteredUsers,sum(user_signUpactivationSuccess_count) as TotalActivatedUsers from daily_analytics_03_2017 where tracking_date BETWEEN "2017-01-01" and "2017-03-21" 
) as t
```

Comment: Your are finding for same dates in different tables...dont you think, it will slow down your response. if you want to do that same why dont you use simple for loop for different tables on basis of months (if your year is same).

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be a better if you store all the sign ups in a single table? It's easier to query and maintain.

```
// the selected range will have to be formatted
$from = '2017-01-01 00:00:00';
$to = '2017-03-15 23:59:59';

// you will have to run this query just once on one particular table 
$query = "SELECT count(*) as number_of_signups FROM tablename WHERE created_on BETWEEN $from AND $to";
```

That being said if you do prefer to store sign ups in different tables on a monthly basis you can query each table with a data range on the timestamp column.

```
// initialization
$count = 0;

// the selected range will have to be formatted
$from = '2017-01-01 00:00:00';
$to = '2017-03-15 23:59:59';

$con=mysqli_connect("yourhost","dbuser","password","your_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// run this query on all the signup tables 
$query = "SELECT count(*) as number_of_signups FROM tablename WHERE created_on BETWEEN $from AND $to";

$result=mysqli_query($con,$query);

// Associative array
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$count += $row['number_of_signups'];

// Free result set
mysqli_free_result($result);

mysqli_close($con);
```

As you can see this part gets really lengthy and complicated:

```
// run this query on all the signup tables 
$query = "SELECT count(*) as number_of_signups FROM tablename WHERE created_on BETWEEN $from AND $to";

$result=mysqli_query($con,$query);

// Associative array
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$count += $row['number_of_signups'];
```

Comment: Thanks Muralidhar Bg,

but table is not single its monthly table how I will do this .

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT  id, country,device,     
            LOWER(MONTHNAME(tracking_date)) AS month,
            YEAR(tracking_date) AS `year`,
            SUM(user_signup_count) AS `monthly_sum`
        FROM daily_analytics_01_2017
        WHERE tracking_date BETWEEN '$first' AND '$last'
        GROUP BY month";
```

Explanation: 
It is not a good idea to create table month wise, create a single table and use that. above query will be enough for that.

```
$first - start date
$last - end date
```

Comment: this is is confusing, you need month wise data but you have month wise table!!

Comment: @DineshGhule Ok, will check it. It's lunch time.

Answer (score 0):

check this code , it will show all previous 12 month login user signup information . you need to change this code as your table field and table name.

```
select date_year y, date_month m, count(*) cnt
            from
            (select id, year(access_time) date_year, month(access_time) date_month, access_time, uid
            from users_login_detail_history
            where date(access_time) >= date_format(concat (year(date_add(date(now()), interval -1 year)), '-' , month(date_add(date(now()), interval -1 year)) , '-1'), '%Y-%m-%d')) login_data
            group by date_year, date_month
            order by date_year, date_month;
```

From this sql this is output result
[image]