# Month level aggregation based on a date column

Tags: sql, hiveql

My first non-aggregated table is like below with the first 3 columns.

I need to create a table with another column with the monthly earnings aggregated for the corresponding department as shown in the red-highlighted column:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 15px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Department</th> 
    <th>Daily Earnings</th>
    <th bgcolor="#ff6633">Dept Monthly Earnings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>02-26-2018</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td bgcolor="#ff6633">60</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>02-27-2018</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>40</td>
    <td bgcolor="#ff6633">140</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>02-28-2018</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td bgcolor="#ff6633">60</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>02-28-2018</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td bgcolor="#ff6633">140</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>03-01-2018</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>150</td>
    <td bgcolor="#ff6633">200</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>03-02-2018</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td bgcolor="#ff6633">200</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>03-02-2018</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td bgcolor="#ff6633">100</td>
  </tr>
  
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

How do I create a table in the above format in Hive/SQL?
Appreciate your help

Comment: See this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42944781/fetch-data-from-monthly-table-mysql-based-on-date-range-ex-data-between-01-jan [Monthwise aggrigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42944781/fetch-data-from-monthly-table-mysql-based-on-date-range-ex-data-between-01-jan)

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       sum(daily_earnings) over (partition by department, trunc(date, 'MON')) as dept_monthly_earnings
from t;
```